# Going to have a chance?

Tags: future-tense, will-vs-going-to

For the sentences below, (it's part of a dialogue)

"I'm learning Swedish. And next week I am going to have a chance to speak it for real. I am going to go to Sweden for 3 weeks"

I feel that it's more appropriate to say "next week I will have a chance..." but I'm not so sure why. Can anyone confirm/negate my "feeling" with reasons?

Comment: They both sound equally appropriate to this US English speaker.

Comment: @stangdon thanks, then is there any difference between these equally appropriate options?

Comment: "going to" is more informal than "will".  But in informal spoken conversation like this, they'd both be fine.

Comment: And in AmE, in informal speech you'd probably hear "I'm gonna have" instead of "I am going to have".  I would actually switch up the word choices in one of the two sentences for another reason - to avoid repeating "I am going to" in two sentences in a row, which can sound a little weird if you do it too much.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine

> will have = going to have
>
> I will have a baby.
>   I'm going to have a baby.
>
> I will have a trip to Sweden.
>   I'm going to have a trip to Sweden.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is a difference between those two forms: "*will + the verb*" and "*to be going to + the verb*"

When somebody uses "*to be going to*" structure it means that one has decided to do something in future and will do it.

While "*will*" is used for defining intentions about future actions, which not surely will be done.

So giving you a rough idea, those forms have a distinction in the implementation probability level.