# "have a trip" vs. "go on a trip"

Tags: word-usage

[From Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/trip)

> a journey to a place, where you stay for a short time, and then come back again
>
> go on/make/take a trip

I completely understand the meaning of it.

[An ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/127456/115654) uses "trip" this way

> I'm going to have a trip to Sweden.

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20a%20trip%2Cgo%20on%20a%20trip&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20trip%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgo%20on%20a%20trip%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgo%20on%20a%20trip%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGo%20on%20a%20trip%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20trip%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cgo%20on%20a%20trip%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bgo%20on%20a%20trip%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGo%20on%20a%20trip%3B%2Cc0) also shows that use.

[image]

Do "have a trip" and "go on a trip" mean the same thing? Are "have a trip" and "go on a trip" interchangeable in any cases?

> Last month, I went on a lovely trip to New York City.
>
> Last month, I had a lovely trip to New York City.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I have a trip", in that form, is unusual. If you look at the actual texts that your Ngram results are taken from, most of them use "have a trip" as part of longer expessions, like

"have a trip coming up"
"have a trip planned"
"had a trip cooked up"
"had a trip scheduled."
"had a trip to take"

There are some examples of "I had a trip" with the meaning of
"I went on a trip". or "I took a trip.", but they are so rare that I would call it unidiomatic.